# div element not autoadjusting itself on zoom

Tags: html, css

I have a form just below the banner on the homepage of a website. The form has a submit button and the whole site is responsive.

On zoom of the browser (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + scroll up/down), the submit button falls out of the div.

The form is in a table (td, tr) format.

```
    filterWrap tr td + td, .filterWrap2 tr td + td {
    border-left: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
}

    .filterWrap td {
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
}

    .filterWrap tr td, .filterWrap2 tr td {
    width: auto;
}
```

Submit button div :

```
<td rowspan="3"><a onclick="jQuery(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;" href="">
            <div class="filterBtn">
            <p>Submit</p>
          </div>
            </a></td>
```

You can check out the form on the banner on this link :http://studio702.biz/venuevista/

Any advice would be really helpful.

Comment: How does .filterBtn look?

Comment: It seems good to me. you said 'the submit buttom falls out of the div' which div ?

Comment: If you zoom the browser...it goes out of the div with the white background,the div which holds it...and it evens falls out of the form border (yellowish orange border for the form).

Comment: Does my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you take the width off filterForm & filterWrap then filterForm will fit to size and stops your problem.

If you provide a JSFiddle I will change the code for you if you need.